# Enabling Kerberos for Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, active-directory, kerberos, spn

I am trying to enable Kerberos for MS SQL Server Reporting Services. I am fairly familiar with Windows security and how it works. However, I am new to Scale Out Deployment and Clustering of Windows Servers. I know I need to add SPNs that direct towards both SSRS web service (using a domain account) and to the database engine. I am a little confused on exactly how the SPNs should be structured. I have looked in Stack Overflow and other resources and most reference a standard deployment without scale-out/clustering.

My questions are:

- Do I structure the SPNs to point to the node, the cluster, both?
- How do I structure the SPNs for each?
- Do I need to include ports?

Here is what I think I need to add:

```
setspn -s http/DEV-CLUSTER.clearcaptions.com ssrsuser
setspn -s MSSQLSvc/DEV-CLUSTER1.clearwd.com DEV-CLUSTER1$
setspn -s MSSQLSvc/DEV-CLUSTER1 DEV-CLUSTER1$
setspn -s MSSQLSvc/DEV-CLUSTER1.clearwd.com:1433 DEV-CLUSTER1$
setspn -s MSSQLSvc/DEV-CLUSTER1:1433 DEV-CLUSTER1$
```

Here are the details of my setup:

**Domain:** clearwd (not my actual domain)

**Server OS:** Windows Server 2016

**Cluster:** DEV-CLUSTER

**Node 1:** DEV-SQL1

**Node 2:** DEV-SQL2

**Role:** DEV-CLUSTER1 (SQL Server / MSSQLSERVER)

**SQL Server Version:** 2016 Enterprise

**SQL Server Name:** DEV-CLUSTER1

**SQL Server Port:** 1433

**SSRS Service Account:** ssrsuser.clearwd.com OR clearwd\ssrsuser

**SSRS Mode:** Native

**SSRS Report Server Web Service URL:** http://DEV-SQL01:80/ReportServer

**SSRS Web Portal URL:** http://DEV-SQL01:80/Reports

Let me know if any other information is needed.

References:

https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/implement-kerberos-delegation-ssrs-0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/register-a-service-principal-name-spn-for-a-report-server?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-report-server-urls-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Microsoft Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046)" can be used  on every involved server to get the overview on a configuration and required SPNs. So far I remember, it supports clustered installations also:

> The Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server is a diagnostic tool
>   that helps troubleshoot Kerberos related connectivity issues with SQL
>   Server, SQL Server Reporting Services, and SQL Server Analysis
>   Services. It can perform the following functions:
>
> - Gather information on OS, Microsoft SQL Server instances and Always On Availability  Group Listeners installed on a server.
> - Report on all SPN and delegation configurations on the server.
> - Identify potential problems in SPNs and delegations. Fix potential SPN problems.

p.s. I think that this kind of questions will have better engagement on a: [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice on DBA Stack Exchange. I downloaded the Tool for Kerberos. It looks like someone added an SPN previously. It shows a status of "Unauthorized". Any idea what that means? There is very little documentation out there on this tool...

Comment: @lawlesm, "Unauthorized". The delegation permissions are not granted on a computer object in Active Directory?

Comment: Delegation was granted. My Windows admin removed and added the SPN back in and it resolved...